# Bluetooth PTS: How to test Bluetooth Proiles using PTS

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-profile

I want to test Bluetooth Profiles in my phone using `Bluetooth PTS(Profile Tuning Suite)` provided by `SIG` ([PTS](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/qualification-test-tools/profile-tuning-suite/)). But I am unable to understand the test cases and how to run them.

For example, I was testing this test case in `PAN Profile`

```
PAN/NAP/IP/APP/BV-05-I

This test involves two Bluetooth devices, with one of the Bluetooth devices sending an IP Ping (ICMP echo request) to the other device. This test case will verify the ability to send and receive control messages.
```

But I am unable to understand how to test it. I searched much on internet about this but there is no helping page or so. Is there any tool or document that can help me regarding `PTS` testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the Launch studio tool from bluetooth. I got reference from that site and it clearly mentioned what to do. And you can select which profiles you want etc. Let me know if you have any questions.